# How to build a GRASS network with node IDs from the line dataset?

Tags: grass-gis, network

I have a dataset of street network links (line geometries). Each network link has a link id, start node id, and end node id attribute. I want to use this network in GRASS, so after importing the lines, I want to create the network nodes. [v.net node](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.html) should create the nodes but as the docs say "nodes created and stored in data layer 2 will not have any associated attribute information".

My question therefore is: How to get the node id information from the links to the nodes?

Input:

```
line layer

line id | from node id | to node id
123     | 901          | 902
124     | 902          | 903
125     | 902          | 1102
```

Result:

```
node layer

node id
901
902
903
1102
```

Comment: I tried to figure it out quite some time, and will probably continue doing so tomorrow; It is easy to build or connect an attribute table to layer 2. Yet I can't figure out how to assign the correct node ID to each row in that table. Just wondering if it will be easier to update (v.to.db) the original table with the new node id's (cat).

Comment: also a work-around will be to create the nodes in Qgis, and use v.net operation=connect in grass, than assign the node original table with v.db.connect or through manage layers.

Comment: @ChrisW No, I want the start and end node ids from the link/edge attribute table as property of the nodes. I need the nodes with ids for further analysis.

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like a deeper table structure manipulation / relating than I was envisioning.

Comment: @underdark to clarify it out - you would like the node table to have the start and end id fields; or would you like each node id (cat in grass) to match the id specified in those fields?

Comment: @dof1985 I would like the node layer to contain the ids from the start/end id fields of the line layer. I've added a short example to the problem description.

Comment: @underdark this was what I thought. Couldn't find a way to do it yet.

Comment: Why don't you create a fourth field at the input, a path_layer node that contains nodes of parts of the line, for example: for line id ='123', path_layer='901','902', this approach would allow you to easily solve your problem?